# Create New Model Instance with API Call in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm unsure how to approach this problem in general in my Django app:

I need to make a call to an API every `n` days. I can make this call and fetch the data required via Python, but where exactly should I put the code?

Do I put the code in a specific `view` and then map the view to a URL and have that URL called whenever I want to create new model instances based on the API call?

Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: I guess this will probably be closed as "primarily opinion based". If you search for "django cron" you'll find quite a few solutions, from running a management command (`manage.py cron`) from your crontab to adding full periodic tasks with *celery*. Your solution is essentially *webcron*. What is best for you depends on your application needs and hosting circumstances.

Comment: But in the case that I use one of those solutions should I be writing a specific view that basically creates a new instance of the model that I am trying to create a new instance of?

Comment: Put the periodic operation into a service layer and maybe explicitly wrap it with [`atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) to get transaction safety. The view is only needed for webcron. Celery and crontab-command don't expose anything to the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I usually do this  is with a combination of custom [Django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/), and then run them wit a scheduled [Cron job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

You can run your custom commands in the same way as you would run the default ones:

```
python manage.py <your_command_name> <your_command_arguments>
```

Comment: So then you would put the code to make the API call in a specific view? And would that code create a new instance of the model?

Comment: Not in the views.py but in the app folder. According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/), any .py file under management>commands inside your app will be usable as a django command

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to have a schedule-able job. [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) works well for this sort of situation.

You would create a task that runs every N days. In that task, you would put your code that calls the API and processing the response as necessary.

Reference:
[Celery Periodic Tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Comment: Celery is good, but I'm more concerned at this point of where exactly to put the logic itself. In a specific view just for calling the API call and updating the database? Do I update the database by creating a new instance of the model from the view I created?

Comment: @AdamThompson, you would create a tasks.py file and put your code in a defined task. You would then create a schedule for that task in your settings and celery beat would take care of running the task according to your schedule. If you want to call the task manually from a view, you can do that too. Read up the celery docs, give it a try, then come back with further questions

Answer (score 1):

> Do I put the code in a specific view

a django `view` is a callable that must accept an HTTP request and return an HTTP response, so unless you need to be able to call your code thru HTTP there's no point in using a view at all, and even if you want to have a view exposing this code it doesn't mean the code doing the API call etc has to live in the view.

Remember that a "django app" is basically a Python package, so beside the django-specific stuff (views, models etc) you can put any module you want and have your views, custom commands etc call on these modules. So just write a module for your API client etc with a function doing the fetch / create model instance / whatever job, and then call this function from where it makes sense (view, custom command called by a cron job, celery task, whatever).